# google glass- location of photos and full path of it

Tags: eclipse, gallery, google-gdk, aero-glass

I tried to open a gallery of images taken with google glass but can't seem to figure ut how to do it. I want to make an application which can open a gallery and do something with my chosen picture. How can I take an access to a gallery?

Comment: This is pretty vague. What programming language are you planning to use for this? What tools? Will it be a website?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I'm using Eclipse( Java) and GDK

Answer (score 0):

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                     Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
```

This line of code helps you in accessing the gallery where images are stored for applications to share.